# How to display a row based on specific columns and values

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have this dataframe:

```
Type    |    Killed
Dog            5
Cat            7
Dog            9
Dog           10
Dog            6
Cat            2
Cow            1
```

I would like to display the row where the number of dogs killed is more than 7.

My desired outcome would be:

```
Type    |    Killed
Dog            9
Dog           10
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select within a column by:

```
df.loc[(df['Killed'] > 7) & (df.index == 'Dog')]
```

Comment: I would like to specify by type Dog too. I am trying to identify the outlier in my dataframe and there are alot of dogs, cats and cows.

df.loc[df['Killed'] > 7] would show all the killed above 7 that also include anything in cats and cows too.

Comment: So you only want `dogs` in your resulting dataframe?

Comment: Yes, I want dog only

Answer (score 0):

You can select data using:

```
data[(data.Type == 'Dog') & (data.Killed > 7)]
```

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd

Type=['Dog','Cat','Dog','Dog','Dog','Cat','Cow']
Killed=[5,7,9,10,6,2,1]

dataset=zip(Type,Killed)

data=pd.DataFrame(dataset)

data.columns=['Type','Killed']
data.loc[((data.Type == 'Dog') & data['Killed'] > 7) ]
```

[image]